# Minimize entire WPF application to System Tray in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, global, system-tray, notifyicon

In my wpf application, I've 4 View windows. I've written following code, which minimizes my main window to system tray when minimized that window. But, I want this effect for all windows in my application(i.e entire wpf application). When I move from one window to another, it should show me icon in system tray for that window as well. Do I need to write same code for all the other windows? Or any other way to achieve this result?

Code written for minimizing Main window to System Tray,

```
public partial class MonthView : MetroWindow
{

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

    public MonthView()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
            calMain.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
            Globals._globalController = new AppController();
            Globals._globalController.appTaskManager.setupLocal();
            Globals._globalController.setMonthViewWindow(this);

            Globals.ni = new NotifyIcon();
            Globals.ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"D:\TimeSheetIcon.ico");
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.Click +=
                delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
                {
                    this.Show();
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                };

    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipTitle = "MonthView";
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipText = "This is main window";
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

NotifyIcon declared globally in Globals.cs

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static NotifyIcon ni;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Create a Class (say WindowBase) that Inherits Window class and then apply this above functionality in this new WindowBase class and then Inherit all your new Windows from this WindowBase class. I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Yes. It's worth to try.